# basic BASH variable call failing in script

Tags: bash, variables, syntax-error, cd

Why is this basic variable call in my script failing?

The script is just below and the errors outputted in terminal after execution are below the script.

Line 8 is the first sudo command.

I am executing this script as root in terminal for now.  It works just fine if I execute the commands manually, one-at-a-time, within terminal...

I would be grateful for any insight.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Enter username
read NAME
echo Enter number
read NUM

sudo (cd /Users/$NAME && tar c .) | (cd /Users/$NUM && tar xf -)

sudo chown -R $NUM:"Domain Users" /Users/$NUM

sudo chmod g+rwx /Users/$NUM
```

---

```
Stephen-Kucker:Desktop root# ./stackoverflowq.txt
Enter username
jsteinberg-c
Enter number
admin
./stackoverflowq.txt: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `cd'
./stackoverflowq.txt: line 8: `sudo (cd /Users/$NAME && tar c .) | (cd /Users/$NUM && tar xf -)'
```

---

Comment: a *minimal* example, please

Comment: Go through this link to know your problem.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-sudo-command-inside-a-script

Comment: Have I not provided an example, Karoly?

Comment: Oh.  Are you saying the hyperlink you've just posted is a minimal example?  I'm unclear as to what your saying/asking.

Comment: user2760626: So you're implying the problem is prefacing my commands with sudo?  I gathered from skimming the hyperlink you posted that this is convoluted and insecure, but why would this produce the SYNTAX errors that are outputted (which I have posted above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo tar -C /Users/$NAME -c . | sudo tar -C /Users/$NUM -xf -
```

Comment: What is the difference between what you have posted and the original code I posted?  This is not rhetorical...I'm seriously asking.

Comment: With your syntax it's not possible to execute multiple commands with sudo.

Comment: @DigitalImpermanence sudo can only run one external executable. You can't run arbitrary shell compound commands like `( subshell groups )` because it's not part of the shell.

Comment: @that other guy: could you maybe say something more about this?  I was not aware that my piped command was an external executable...

Comment: @DigitalImpermanence It wasn't, that was the problem. `tar` is an external command, so `sudo tar ..` is valid. `(` is not a command at all, so `sudo ( ..` is not valid.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, that makes perfect sense.  Do you have any insight as to why when I execute the script now the piped command runs but then the chown command fails as follows: chown: Domain Users: illegal group name?  Previously, when running these commands as root one-at-a-time in terminal I received no such error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `-s` option to pass an arbitrary shell command (like the pipeline shown) to the shell with `sudo`:

```
sudo -s "(cd /Users/$NAME && tar c .) | (cd /Users/$NUM && tar xf -)"
```

Comment: Okay.  I will test your suggestion.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.  I will jump back in a minute with an update.

Comment: This is the most straightforward solution (assuming it works; I didn't test it), but Cyrus's answer is probably better by eliminating the need to change the working directories.

Comment: When I run your suggestion the terminal returns:

chown: Domain Users: illegal group name

...which I do not understand because when I run these same commands one at a time from terminal I do not receive this error.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that command actually worked. Group names cannot contain spaces. In any case, it's a completely separate problem from what you posted in this question.

Comment: I've run these commands as root in Terminal numerous times with absolutely zero problems...as recently as yesterday.  That's why I included them in my script...because they worked flawlessly.  I had another user on this site run them three minutes ago and he also reported that they run without error from Terminal.  I've posted this separate issue as a new question.